# Icons disappeared after upgrading the font ‘Font Awesome’ to version 5

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’ve upgraded the ‘Font Awesome’ font to version 5, and then the icons in my application disappeared. I also still have the old js for backwards compatability but my checkbox doesn't have an icon anymore.

I don't know what exactly has changed in this upgrade to be honest.

Can anyone help me?

**WORKING FIDDLE**

```css
.checkbox {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.checkbox label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.checkbox label::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.checkbox label::after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #555555;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:focus+label::before {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f00c";
}

.checkbox.error-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  content: "\f00d";
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+label {
  opacity: 0.65;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+label::before {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.checkbox.checkbox-circle label::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.checkbox.checkbox-inline {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #062f4f;
  border-color: #062f4f;
}

.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  color: #fff;
}

.checkbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #d9534f;
  border-color: #d9534f;
}

.checkbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  color: #fff;
}

.checkbox-info input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  border-color: #5bc0de;
}

.checkbox-info input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  color: #fff;
}

.checkbox-warning input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
  border-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.checkbox-warning input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  color: #fff;
}

.checkbox-success input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-color: #5cb85c;
}

.checkbox-success input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  color: #fff;
}

.radio {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.radio label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.radio label::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.radio label::after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #555555;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -o-transform: scale(0, 0);
  transform: scale(0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.8, -0.33, 0.2, 1.33);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.8, -0.33, 0.2, 1.33);
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.8, -0.33, 0.2, 1.33);
  transition: transform 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.8, -0.33, 0.2, 1.33);
}

.radio input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]:focus+label::before {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]:checked+label::after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}

.radio input[type="radio"]:disabled+label {
  opacity: 0.65;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]:disabled+label::before {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.radio.radio-inline {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.radio-primary input[type="radio"]+label::after {
  background-color: #092756;
}

.radio-primary input[type="radio"]:checked+label::before {
  border-color: #092756;
}

.radio-primary input[type="radio"]:checked+label::after {
  background-color: #092756;
}

.radio-danger input[type="radio"]+label::after {
  background-color: #d9534f;
}

.radio-danger input[type="radio"]:checked+label::before {
  border-color: #d9534f;
}

.radio-danger input[type="radio"]:checked+label::after {
  background-color: #d9534f;
}

.radio-info input[type="radio"]+label::after {
  background-color: #092756;
}

.radio-info input[type="radio"]:checked+label::before {
  border-color: #092756;
}

.radio-info input[type="radio"]:checked+label::after {
  background-color: #092756;
}

.radio-warning input[type="radio"]+label::after {
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.radio-warning input[type="radio"]:checked+label::before {
  border-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.radio-warning input[type="radio"]:checked+label::after {
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.radio-success input[type="radio"]+label::after {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}

.radio-success input[type="radio"]:checked+label::before {
  border-color: #5cb85c;
}

.radio-success input[type="radio"]:checked+label::after {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
  <input type="checkbox" id="coreBanking" name="hasHost" checked="" disabled="">
  <label for="coreBanking">Core banking</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Pick a new icon from the current icon collection... problem solved

Comment: but I dont know where the icon is in my css. i didnt make this code. I think it has something to do with : `content: "\f00c";`

Comment: It is exactly that. `\f00c` is the icon code.

Comment: I'm used to use fas fa-check for example. How do I know what are these codes?

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/icons/credit-card?style=regular Look at the bottom of the page. This icon's code is `\f09d`.

Comment: You picked the SVG JS. If you want your webfont (that you are using in your CSS) to work, you should use the webfont version of FA5.

Comment: It is this one: https://fontawesome.com/icons/check?style=solid the code is the same so it should work

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that need changing here.

- You're loading the JS file, but you'd be better with the CSS link if you're including the icons in pseudo elements.
- The name of the font has changed from `'FontAwesome'` to `Font Awesome\ 5 Free` and you need to add `font-weight: 900` for the icon to appear too.

Here's a working example:

```css
.checkbox {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.checkbox label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.checkbox label::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.checkbox label::after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #555555;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:focus+label::before {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
  content: "\f00c";
  font-weight: 900;
}

.checkbox.error-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  content: "\f00d";
  font-weight: 900;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+label {
  opacity: 0.65;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+label::before {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.checkbox.checkbox-circle label::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.checkbox.checkbox-inline {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #062f4f;
  border-color: #062f4f;
}

.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  color: #fff;
}

.checkbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #d9534f;
  border-color: #d9534f;
}

.checkbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  color: #fff;
}

.checkbox-info input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  border-color: #5bc0de;
}

.checkbox-info input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  color: #fff;
}

.checkbox-warning input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
  border-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.checkbox-warning input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  color: #fff;
}

.checkbox-success input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-color: #5cb85c;
}

.checkbox-success input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  color: #fff;
}

.radio {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.radio label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.radio label::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.radio label::after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #555555;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0, 0);
  -o-transform: scale(0, 0);
  transform: scale(0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.8, -0.33, 0.2, 1.33);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.8, -0.33, 0.2, 1.33);
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.8, -0.33, 0.2, 1.33);
  transition: transform 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.8, -0.33, 0.2, 1.33);
}

.radio input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]:focus+label::before {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]:checked+label::after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}

.radio input[type="radio"]:disabled+label {
  opacity: 0.65;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]:disabled+label::before {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.radio.radio-inline {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.radio-primary input[type="radio"]+label::after {
  background-color: #092756;
}

.radio-primary input[type="radio"]:checked+label::before {
  border-color: #092756;
}

.radio-primary input[type="radio"]:checked+label::after {
  background-color: #092756;
}

.radio-danger input[type="radio"]+label::after {
  background-color: #d9534f;
}

.radio-danger input[type="radio"]:checked+label::before {
  border-color: #d9534f;
}

.radio-danger input[type="radio"]:checked+label::after {
  background-color: #d9534f;
}

.radio-info input[type="radio"]+label::after {
  background-color: #092756;
}

.radio-info input[type="radio"]:checked+label::before {
  border-color: #092756;
}

.radio-info input[type="radio"]:checked+label::after {
  background-color: #092756;
}

.radio-warning input[type="radio"]+label::after {
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.radio-warning input[type="radio"]:checked+label::before {
  border-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.radio-warning input[type="radio"]:checked+label::after {
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.radio-success input[type="radio"]+label::after {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}

.radio-success input[type="radio"]:checked+label::before {
  border-color: #5cb85c;
}

.radio-success input[type="radio"]:checked+label::after {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
  <input type="checkbox" id="coreBanking" name="hasHost" checked="" disabled="">
  <label for="coreBanking">Core banking</label>
</div>
```

Comment: it looks a bit stranger now (not centered) :/ but thanks

Comment: It's just a change in the padding that's needed to fix that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: fa-solid-900.ttf Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: fa-solid-900.woff Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)